# Xcode Source Control Git

Tags: xcode, git

When you create a new xcode project, there is a checkbox, which you can check if you want to use a git repository on your mac. I did not check that box, so right now I don't have access to source control resources. How can I start using git with my project?

Comment: Theres a source control section in the menu somewhere where you can check or uncheck 'Enable source control'

Answer (score 4):

I think you would just need to setup a local git repository.

Open terminal on your Mac and type the following commands:

```
cd <DirectoryYourCodeIsIn>
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

Also, restart XCode after this is completed.